# Is there a way to predict the amount of memory needed for ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've just starting using ffmpeg and I want to create a VR180 video from a list of images with resolution 11520x5760. (Images are 80MB each, i have for now just 225 for testing.)

I used the code :
`ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i "%06d.png" "output.mp4"`

I ran out of my 8G RAM and ffmpeg crashed.
So I've create a 10G swap, ffmpeg filled it up and crashed.

Is there a way to know how much is needed for an ffmpeg command to run properly ?

Answer (score 2):

Please provide output of the `ffmpeg` command when you run it.

I'm assuming FFmpeg will transcode to H.264, so it will create a H.264 encoder. Most memory sits in the lookahead queue and reference buffers. For H.264, the default for `--rc-lookahead` is 40. I believe H.264 allows something like 2x4=8 references (?) + current frame(s) (there can be frame-threading), so let's say roughly 50 frames in total. Frame size for YUV420P data is 1.5xresolution, so 1.5x11520x5760x50=~5GB. Add to that encoder-specific data which roughly doubles this, so 10GB should be enough.

If 8+10GB is not enough, my rough handwavy calculation is probably not precise enough. Your options are:

- significantly reduce [`--rc-lookahead`](http://www.chaneru.com/Roku/HLS/X264_Settings.htm#rc-lookahead), [`--threads`](http://www.chaneru.com/Roku/HLS/X264_Settings.htm#threads) and [`--level`](http://www.chaneru.com/Roku/HLS/X264_Settings.htm#level) so there's fewer frames alive at a time - read the documentation for each of these options to understand what they do, what their defaults are and what to change them to to reduce memory usage (see e.g. note [here](https://silentaperture.gitlab.io/mdbook-guide/encoding/x264.html#ratecontrol-lookahead) for `--rc-lookahead`).
- You can also use a different (less complex) codec that has smaller memory requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I don't understand anything you are saying, which is great. I'll learn about everything you said and come back to you. (Either way I'm wondering if there really is a way to "anticipate" the amount of memory needed with a specific command, why isn't it built-in inside ffmpeg ? Or an option ? - instead of just crashing, it can say : "This command requires at least xG of memory")